Salesforce apex:image : impossible to load the image
I need your help to find the reason because  since yesterday ,  the image (logo)  didn't appear in my template  with the following code :
I created a template which generated pdf file with logo and signature .
 <apex:image value="https://c.fra32.content.sfdc-urlt2q.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015b0000001kbLy&oid=00Db0000000ImQQ&lastMod=118425000&InstHostname=c.eu2.content.force.com"/>

the problem is I tried to change apex:image with but nothing change :
 <img  src="https://c.eu2.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015b0000001kbLy&oid=00Db0000000ImQQ&lastMod=1440418425000" />

I tried to find here : visual force developer guide  if there is news about apex:image

PDF generation is done using somewhat external Java library called Flying Saucer. The Document is effectively the same after domain migration? And it still has "externally available image" ticked?
The PDF engine is on different server than the main app so fetching an image counts as a callout. Even though technically it's a callout to "self". Check if you have remote site settings pointing to old domain. And if you do add / change it to allowlist the new domain too.
It'd be easier if you'd have proper MyDomain enabled (for LWC for example), the urls generated with mycompany.my.salesforce.com have higher chance of surviving the datacentre migrations... But it's not 100%
